# Regarding execution of .robot files for robot framework in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, robotframework

As it is specified everywhere for executing robot scripts you have to create maven project.I created the maven project and have added all the dependencies and plugin required for the execution. But when i create the maven project then by default a class ic created as AppTest.java in my src/test folder.Now when i add this .robot file in my test folder or main folder.It is not getting executed.Moreover i have a confusion how to execute these scripts.Please help me with this.Where should i place these file so that they could be executed.

Comment: read [ask] and improve your question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that at this time (7 months after your question) you've found a solution for the problem. If yes, I suggest you share it with the community.

Here's my solution, assuming that you're using Google Chrome:

1. Open the Edit Configurations window for your maven project, select the tab "Parameters", and in the field "Command Line" type "robotframework:run". It should look like this:

[image: Set the command line]

2. Then you select the tab "Runner" and add the property "webdriver.chrome.driver=/path-to-the-webdriver". It shoud look like this:

[image: Path to the webdriver]

*(note: uncheck the "Skip tests" check box. Mine is checked on the screenshot because I was testing other things.)*

What's a little frustrating is that we can be misled by the error messages which say that you have to set the environment variable "webdriver.chrome.driver". In this case, we're tempted to add this variable to the field "Environment variables".

However, IntelliJ creates its own environment on run. That's why the field "Environment variables" doesn't work. When you add that property to the "Properties" box, the IntelliJ will convert it into a parameter in the run command, which will create the proper environment for the project.

Something like this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/acampos/study/robotframework01
-Dmaven.home=/home/acampos/programs/idea-IU-172.4343.14/plugins/maven/lib/maven3
-Dclassworlds.conf=/home/acampos/programs/idea-IU-172.4343.14/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf
-javaagent:/home/acampos/programs/idea-IU-172.4343.14/lib/idea_rt.jar=36889:/home/acampos/programs/idea-IU-172.4343.14/bin
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath /home/acampos/programs/idea-IU-172.4343.14/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher
-Didea.version=2017.2.5
HERE!!!
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/home/acampos/programs/chromedriver/chromedriver robotframework:run
```

So, when you run your maven project it will run the goal that's described on the Parameters tab, Command line field.

I hope it helps. And, again, if you've found another solution, please share with us.

Good luck!